# Making a list of size n while taking the inputs for the list in a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to take the input of the list all in the same line.
However i get the following error

```
> val = [int(input().split())]
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

here is my code

```
n=int(input("Enter an input: "))
val=[]
val = val[:n]  
val = [int(input().split())]
print (val)
```

Comment: `input().split()` is a list. You cannot convert it to an int.

Comment: What is your input value and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to your list using successive inputs.  Here is something that may be what you are looking for:

```
ans = None
values = []
while ans != '':
    ans = input('enter value: ')
    if ans.isdigit():
        and = int(ans)
    if ans.strip() == '':
        break
    values.append(and)
print('\n'.join(str(x) for x in values)
```

This will take inputs until the input is blank, converting any input that is a number to an int since input return values are always strings

Alternatively you can directly get a list of space separated numbers. This approach will fail if a non-digit value is entered:

```
print('enter space-separated numbers')
values = [int(val) for val in input().split()]
```